# Bematech com Nodejs

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando conectar impressora *bematech MP-4200 TH* com **NodeJs** mas não consigo.

```js
var stream = fs.createWriteStream('/dev/ttyACM0', {
    encoding: 'utf16le'
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando executo não acontece nada, não esta imprimindo.

Tentei também o comando `echo "teste impressão MP4200TH" > /dev/ttyACM0` pelo terminal também não imprime.